# Getting the Position Stream from Geolocator into StreamBuilder Flutter

Tags: flutter, stream, flutter-dependencies

I'm just starting with Flutter and very new to State/Stream/BloC concepts. I'm trying to update a `FlutterMap` center based on the coordinates from a `Geolocator()`'s `Position` stream. At the moment I'm just calling `setState()` updating a variable with the new value, but next I'll be trying using the Bloc pattern instead.. 
Now, as well as I set the center on the coordinates of the Position coming from the stream I also set a `Marker` on the same coordinates. I was expecting to see a Steady marker in the center of the screen and a moving map underneath but is the opposite.. the Map is steady and the Icon is moving.. Can you see where I got it wrong?
Also, for the `stream:` property of the `StreamBuilder` how would I get to pass the stream from `Geolocator()` as an event?

Many thanks for your time and help.

This is the Stream:

```
StreamSubscription positionStream = _geolocator
        .getPositionStream(locationOptions)
        .listen((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _position = position;
      });
      print(
          _position.latitude.toString() + ',' + _position.longitude.toString()); // ok
    });
```

And this is the Map and the Marker:

```
Container(
                height: 670,
                width: 370,
                child: FlutterMap(
                  options: MapOptions(
                    center: LatLng(_position.latitude, _position.longitude),
                    minZoom: 16.0,
                    maxZoom: 19.0,
                  ),
                  layers: [
                    TileLayerOptions(
//                        urlTemplate:
//                        'https://api.openrouteservice.org/mapsurfer/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?api_key=omitted',
                        urlTemplate:
                            'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                        subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                        keepBuffer: 20),
                    new MarkerLayerOptions(
                      markers: [
                        new Marker(
                            point: new LatLng(
                                _position.latitude, _position.longitude),
                            height: 200,
                            width: 200,
                            builder: (context) => IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  iconSize: 60,
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    print('icon tapped');
                                  },
                                )),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. I didn't assign any `MapController()`.
So I created one and assign it to the `FlutterMap`. Inside the `setState()` I added `_controller.move(LatLng(_position.latitude, _position.longitude), 16.0);` and now the behaviour is the expected one. Steady Icon in the center of the screen and a moving map underneath. 
Hope this will help others.
But still I will try to achieve the same with a BLoC pattern. 
Cheers